# The command “adb” not working as expected in a macOS shell script but works fine in the macOS terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, batch-file, adb

I have a `.bat` script with some [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) commands that I want to run on a Mac. So I changed the extension to `.sh` and changed the mode so it's executable.

Every line works fine when I enter them in the macOS terminal, but when I run the `.sh` file errors would occur.

For example:

```
adb shell "echo 1 > xxxxx"
```

Results in:

```
Permission denied can't create xxxx: No such file or directory
```

When I try to push some file in the same directory as the script, it shows the status of the transmission like:

```
13.2 MB/s (525534 bytes in 0.038s)
```

but then followed by:

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you looked at this thread on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009716/how-can-i-remount-my-android-system-as-read-write-in-a-bash-script-using-adb)? You should also probably be renaming that file `.sh` instead of `.command` and the beginning of then script should have the line `#!/bin/bash -l`.

Comment: Can you access the adb shell prompt? `adb shell`

Comment: @JakeGould Thank you! I've changed it to `.sh`, now `adb remount` works, but the `adb shell echo 1 > xxx` still doesn't work. I've tried some other `adb shell` commands looks like there weren't any complains

Comment: @BlueDrink9 Thank you! I can access the `adb shell` in the terminal with no problem. :) When I change the script to `.sh`, looks like `adb shell` works fine too. But `adb shell "echo 1 > xxx"` does not work :(

Comment: Can you try specifying an absolute path for the output? eg `adb shell "echo test > /data/data/test.txt"`

Comment: @BlueDrink9 Thanks:) Sorry about the confusion. I've done that, I just sensored the names in this question lol. The exact command works fine when I enter them manually in the terminal of MacOS.

Comment: Yes, that is because you have permission for the directory under OSX, but probably not in the phone directory. That is why using `su` worked.

Comment: @BlueDrink9 You are exactly right :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed

`adb shell "echo 1 > xxxxx"`

to

`adb shell "echo 1 > xxxxx" \| su`

and it worked.

I've found the solution here: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/85b288

Comment: Please edit your answer with the final command for clarity

Comment: @BlueDrink9 Thanks :) I've edited the answer.